DAX function for highlights latest value in each month
I want to hightlights new product in my table that never been sold before in previous month.
Here is my data example.



DATE
Product




1/1/2024
carrot


1/1/2024
cabbage


1/1/2024
grape


1/2/2024
carrot


1/2/2024
cabbage


1/2/2024
grape


1/2/2024
mango


1/3/2024
carrot


1/3/2024
orange


1/3/2024
grape


1/3/2024
mango


1/4/2024
carrot


1/4/2024
orange


1/4/2024
grape


1/4/2024
lemon



In Power BI, I create a table from visualisation and a slicer for fiter Date. I want to hightlights new product in my table that never been sold before in previous month. Then if I select date 1/2/2024 the table should show as below with hightlight at "mango".



DATE
Product




1/2/2024
carrot


1/2/2024
cabbage


1/2/2024
grape


1/2/2024
mango



if I select date 1/3/2024 the table should show as below with hightlight at "orange".



DATE
Product




1/3/2024
carrot


1/3/2024
orange


1/3/2024
grape


1/3/2024
mango



if I select date 1/4/2024 the table should show as below with hightlight at "Lemon".



DATE
Product




1/4/2024
carrot


1/4/2024
orange


1/4/2024
grape


1/4/2024
lemon



Please show me how i can create function for formatting my table.
Thank you
**** My data was import from sql database with DirectQuery mode. Pleas consider this for DAX function if it can be use ****

You can use PREVIOUSMONTH to help with this.
Try a measure similar to this:
New Product = 
  var curProducts = DISTINCT(YourTable[Product])
  var prevMonthProducts = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT(YourTable[Product]),
      PREVIOUSMONTH(YourTable[DATE]) // or use your Date/Calendar table if you have one
    )
  var result = COUNTROWS( INTERSECT( curProducts, prevMonthProducts ))
  return IF(result > 0, "", 1)

To give you a result of:

You can then use this measure in Conditional Formatting
